# "No implicits found" when creating a Flink DataStream from a collection of Case Classes

Tags: scala, apache-flink, implicit

I'm trying to do a `flink` scala api hello world but am unable to replicate the beginning tutorial snippet seen here from https://www.slideshare.net/dataArtisans/apache-flink-datastream-api-basics/20

[image]

My attempted copy of it is:

```
  val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
  case class Order(user: String, product: String, amount: Double, proctime: Int, rowtime: Int)

  def basic() = {
    val seq = (1 to 50).map { i => Order(s"User" + (i % 10).toString, "Product" + (i % 20), 2.0 * (4 * i +.5 * i * i -.1 * i * i * i), i * 10, i * 3) }
    val ds: DataStream[Order] = env.fromElements(seq:_*)
```

The implicit is not working however, giving

> Error:(21, 30) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type 
>   org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[com.blazedb.spark.FlinkDemo.Order]

[image: c]

What needs to be changed here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
```

in order to import implicit `TypeInformation[T]`

https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-scala/src/main/scala/org/apache/flink/api/scala/package.scala#L49